# Python Function call stack: train_function error

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
indices[124,9] = 8871 is not in [0, 8871)
     [[node sequential_11/embedding-layer/embedding_lookup (defined at <ipython-input-77-c69fd3d9a614>:22) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_19388]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node sequential_11/embedding-layer/embedding_lookup:
 sequential_11/embedding-layer/embedding_lookup/15542 (defined at C:\Users\OMER\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\contextlib.py:113)

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I'm getting the above error can you help with this?

Comment: I don't think `[0, 8871)` is Python, try: `8871 not in range(0, 8871)` or `not (0 <= 8871 < 8871)`.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you intended to do and what you intended to happen? The only code you are showing is not valid Python. Please take a look at the [ask] and [mcve] help pages how to best help us help you.